# Selecting the Maximum Value of Group By Parameter

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite

I have some accident data that I am trying to query in Python via SQLite3. I'm trying to determine which day of the week had the most accidents in a particular year-month pair. The data has the following fields:

Accidents: Accident_Index | Year | Month | Day_of_Week

where Day_of_Week ranges from 1-7 with Sunday being 1. The result should be in ascending order by years, then months, and the new table should contain the following columns:

max_dayofweek: Year | Month | Day_of_Week | Num_of_Accidents

So far, I have the following:

```
query = '''
    SELECT Year, Month, Day_of_Week, count(*) as Num_of_Accidents
    from Accidents
    group by Year, Month, Day_of_Week
    order by Year, Month
'''
max_dayofweek = pd.read_sql_query(query, conn)
```

But this returns:

```
    Year    Month   Day_of_Week     Num_of_Accidents
0   2009    1       1               623
1   2009    1       2               1095
2   2009    1       3               1197
3   2009    1       4               1244
4   2009    1       5               1123
5   2009    1       6               1404
6   2009    1       7               1114
7   2009    2       1               592
8   2009    2       2               919
9   2009    2       3               887
10  2009    2       4               1013
11  2009    2       5               915
12  2009    2       6               1032
13  2009    2       7               824
```

But the output should look like:

```
    Year    Month   Day_of_Week     Num_of_Accidents
0   2009    1       6               1404
1   2009    2       6               1032
```

And so on...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQLite, you can do this as:

```
with ym as (
      select Year, Month, Day_of_Week, count(*) as Num_of_Accidents
      from Accidents
      group by Year, Month, Day_of_Week
     )
select ym.*
from ym
where ym.Num_of_Accidents = (select max(ym2.Num_of_Accidents)
                             from ym ym2
                             where ym2.year = ym.year and ym2.month = ym.month
                            )
order by Year, Month;
```

That said, your calculation is likely to be off, because some dows occur four times in a month and some occur five times (unless you are using some sort of fiscal calendar). Unfortunately, you don't have the specific date, so you cannot take this into account.

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly what I needed. I didn't have an issue due to some dows occuring 4 vs 5 times. Probably because I'm bucketing the number of accidents each month into the specific day of the week they occurred. Thanks again for your help!